# OData, JayData, and node.js: Cannot find ExpressionVisitor.js

Tags: node.js, odata, jaydata

I ran `npm install odata-server`, but calling `require('odata-server')` fails with the following:

```
Using JayLint for code parsing

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './Types/Expressions/Visitors/ExpressionVisitor.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anewman/node_modules/odata-server/lib/jaydata/lib/index.js:28:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
```

Comment: node -v, npm -v? looks like a bug in odata-server, have you posted an issue?

Comment: require('odata-server') is working for me after npm install. Did the reinstall fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the module and check that the missing file is there. Please also check your NODE_PATH settings because the library can not find the acorn parser module under `~/node_modules/odata-server/lib/jaydata/node-modules/acorn`